# Triple Integral $\iiint\limits_Wz\frac{e^{2x^2+2y^2}}2\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $W=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=1,0\le z\le4\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

They ask me find the following:

$W$ is the solid bounded by the limited right circular cylinder: $$ x^2+y^2=1$$ and the planes: $$z=0, z=4$$
must calculate:
$$\iiint_W z\frac{e^{2x^2+2y^2}}{2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
My procedure was as follows, I have in cylindrical coordinates:
$$ x = r\cos(\theta ), y = r\sin(\theta ), z = z, r^2=x^2+y^2$$
therefore it poses work well
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^4z\frac{e^{2r^{2}}}{2}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$
but at this point I find problems to develop this integral as I could not develop any method; by parts or change by Fubini. Any advice will be of much help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handling $z$ term is easy as it is just a polynomial.

Handling $\theta$ is easy too.

Now to handle the $r$ term. You miss out an $r$. remember when using cylindrical coordinate. We have to use $r\,dr\,d\theta$ rather than just $dr\,d\theta$. This simplifies the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question was edited, but it currently does have the $r$.

Comment: I have edited, thanks

Comment: cool, one approach to handle the $r$ part is let $u=2r^2$.

Comment: thank you very much everyone, the answer is $$(e^{2}-1)2\pi$$